# Reuse log in state for all tests with pytest-playwright and Django

Tags: pytest, playwright, pytest-django, playwright-python

I'm trying to create a pytest fixture that will allow all my tests to reuse a single authenticated context. The goal is for the fixture to run once, yielding a context. Then the other tests can just reuse the authenticated context via the fixture. I also need this solution to run in CI.

The code below runs, but `test_home` does not retain a logged in state for some reason and redirects to the log in page.

**conftest.py**

```py
import logging
import os

import pytest
from django.conf import settings
from user.models import User
from user.tests.factories import UserFactory

@pytest.fixture()
def user() -> User:
    return UserFactory()

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE", "true")
settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS += ["127.0.0.1"]

@pytest.mark.django_db
@pytest.fixture()
def playwright_user(user):
    password = "********"
    email = "bob@example.com"
    user.email = email
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    logging.info("Saved test user")

@pytest.fixture()
def logged_in(
    live_server,
    playwright,
    playwright_user,
) -> None:
    """Create context (i.e. general configuration) for Playwright"""
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context(
        base_url="http://127.0.0.1:8080", storage_state="auth.json"
    )
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("http://127.0.0.1:8080/")
    page.get_by_placeholder("E-mail address login").fill("bob@exmpale.com")
    page.get_by_placeholder("Password password").fill("*******")
    page.get_by_role("button", name="Sign In").click()
    storage = context.storage_state(path="auth.json")
    logging.info("Created authenticated context")
    context.close()


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def context(playwright):
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context(
        base_url="http://127.0.0.1:8080", storage_state="auth.json"
    )
    yield context
    context.close()
```

**test_integration.py** (note: the `home` page below is log in protected.)

```py
import logging

import pytest
from django.urls import reverse
from playwright.sync_api import Page, sync_playwright

pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db

def test_login(live_server, logged_in):
    logging.info("Logged In")
    pass


def test_home(
    context,
    live_server,
    page: Page,
) -> None:
    """Create a new Organization Parent Type"""
    page.goto(reverse("home"))
    # redirects to the log in page instead of taking me to the home page :(
```

I'm not sure why `test_home` goes to a log in screen rather than directly opening the `home` page. If things were working properly it should go directly to the home page. Any help would be really appreciated!